# Formatting the JSON date

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

My application is getting a datetime value from JSON in the following format:

```
Created
"/Date(1335232596000)/"
```

To show the value on the front end, I wrote a js function with the following code:

```
 return new Date(parseInt(date.substr(6)));
```

This however, shows the following:

```
Mon Apr 23 2012 20:56:36 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

Any suggestions on how can I get the date to display like this:

```
"04/23/2012 - 08:56:26pm CST"
```

Comment: Do you always want it in Standard time, even if it is currently Daylight time? Do you also want Central time every time, or to use the current browser time zone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Formatting a date in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the official [jQuery Globalization Plugin format method](https://github.com/jquery/globalize/blob/master/README.md#format):

```
Globalize.format( new Date(1955,10,5), "yyyy/MM/dd" );
// "1955/11/05"
Globalize.format( new Date(1955,10,5), "dddd MMMM d, yyyy" );
// "Saturday November 5, 1955"
```

There are a ton of [date formatting options](https://github.com/jquery/globalize/blob/master/README.md#dates) available.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to format your date using the date object methods: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Or use some external library like [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/).

Here is a question about this: [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

`Date` is an Javascript object. You can format it by using the Date Object Methods http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

```
var mydate = new Date()
var hours = mydate.getHours()
```

Answer (score 1):

> My application is getting a datetime value from JSON in the following
>   format:
>
> Created "/Date(1335232596000)/"

Instead of using a `DateTime` property on your view model that is serialized by the `JavaScriptSerializer` using the aformentioned format, use a string property and do the formatting on the server => use a real view model.

Here's how you could format this DateTime

```
DateTime date = ...
string created = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:sstt ") + GetTimeZoneName(date);
// pass the created string to the view
```

where `TimeZoneName` is defined like this:

```
public static string GetTimeZoneName(DateTime date)
{
    var name = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(date)
        ? TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.DaylightName
        : TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName;

    var newName = "";
    var parts = name.Split(' ');
    foreach (var s in parts)
    {
        if (s.Length >= 1)
        {
            newName += s.Substring(0, 1);
        }
    }
    return newName;
}
```

Now inside your view you will receive the date formatted as it has to be formatted. And if for some reason you also needed this date under the form of a javascript `Date` object inside the view you could also leave the DateTime property on the view model and the serializer will include both.